# Why does PostgreSQL rolls back my INSERT statement?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rails-postgresql, heroku-postgres

I have a model where I am storing stuff. When the value of a boolean attribute (action_type) is false, then PostgreSQL rolls back the INSERT query for some reason.

```
create_table :process_flows do |t|
      t.integer :campaign_id
      t.integer :position
      t.string :description
      t.string :typestr
      t.float :action_number
      t.boolean :action_type
      t.string :action_on_donation
      t.integer :created_by
      t.integer :updated_by
      t.timestamps
end
```

My View file looks like:

```
<%= form_for [@org, @campaign, @process_flow] do |f| %>
        <%= render "shared/errors", :target => @process_flow %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :description %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :description %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :typestr, 'Type of organization' %><br /><br />
            <%= f.select :typestr, options_for_select([["Point of collection", "PC", :selected => true], ["Your Organization", "O"], ["Bank / Payment Gateway", "B"], ["Intermediary", "I"], ["Recipient Charity Project", "R"]]) %><br /><br />
        </div>
        <%= f.select :action_on_donation, options_for_select([["100% (Unchanged)", "U", :selected => true], ["Increase", "A"], ["Decrease", "S"]]) %>
        the donation 
        by
        <%= f.text_field :action_number, :style=>"width: 30px;", :value => '0' %>
        <%= f.select :action_type, options_for_select([["Percent", '1', :selected => true], ["Flat Amount", '0']]) %>
        <div>
            <%= f.submit 'Add', :class=>'button' %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you dig the INSERT SQL out of your logs? And are there any error messages anywhere?

Comment: Started POST "/orgs/fooddepot/campaigns/buy-food-give-food/process_flows" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-14 15:02:45 +0530
  Processing by ProcessFlowsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"if4a6oKMnidkdIJQp9dOL4pVX8FdyiPGao3McTij6Tg=", "process_flow"=>{"description"=>"Testing", "typestr"=>"I", "action_on_donation"=>"S", "action_number"=>"10", "action_type"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Add", "org_id"=>"fooddepot", "campaign_id"=>"buy-food-give-food"}

Comment: SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
ProcessFlow Load (0.4ms)  SELECT position FROM "process_flows" WHERE ( process_flows.campaign_id = '1') ORDER BY position DESC, position ASC LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/orgs/fooddepot/campaigns/buy-food-give-food/process_flows?layout=settings_campaign
Completed 302 Found in 250ms

Comment: Do you have the log entries for the INSERT? I don't see `action_type` in there. I'm really wondering if the Boolean is getting to the database as `0` or `'f'`.

Comment: The ROLLBACK comes from your code, it's not created by PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL only logs queries that are sent by your application.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen on many platforms.

The most typical cause for this is a missing COMMIT.  PostgreSQL will roll back open transactions when the connection is closed.

Another possibility is that you have a code branch which is not executing even though you expect it to be.

In these cases it is important to debug your code by walking through it (there is not enough code here to go on) and determine whether the insert is being sent at all and whether a commit is ever issued.